# Extending List<T> in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, guava, java-8, default-method

I often want to map one list into another list. For example if I had a list of people, and I wanted a list of their names, I would like to do:

**GOAL**

```
List<Person> people = ... ;

List<String> names = people.map(x -> x.getName());
```

Something like this is possible with Java 8:

**JAVA 8 VERSION**

```
List<String> names = people.stream()
                           .map(x -> x.getName())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this is clearly not as nice. In fact, I think using Guava is cleaner:

**GUAVA VERSION**

```
List<String> names = Lists.transform(people, x -> x.getName());
```

However, I do like chaining. So, is my goal possible?

I have heard people say that Java 8 default methods are similar to C# extension methods. With a C# extension method, I could easily add a helper method to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TRet> Map<T, TRet>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, TRet> selector)
{
    return list.Select(selector);
}
```

However I can't figure out how to use default methods to *extend an existing interface*.

Also, this is obviously a trivial example. In general, I would like to be able to extend the `List<T>` and `Iterable<T>` interfaces to make interacting with the streams api easier.

Comment: Note that `collect(Collectors.toList())` will return a copy, whereas `Lists.transform` returns a view.

Comment: You can always create your own interfaces and create code which looks like `transform(list).using(x -> x.getName())`

Comment: FYI: instead of `x -> x.getName()`, it'd be simpler to use `Foo::getName`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman true I could do that. I'm still deciding whether or not I prefer the lambda syntax though...  As of now I think devs find it easier to read lambdas than method references, especially when coming from coffeescript or C# or whatever.

Comment: @Alden, Java type system is not as expressive as, say, Scala, and Java is not a dynamic language, so it is impossible (by the language and library authors, that is) to improve the API to do what you want without either losing flexibility (e.g. simple parallelism and laziness) or adding **huge** bloat to existing interfaces (if e.g. they were to add `map` method directly to `List` class). And because Java does not provide any means to extend existing types, you're in fact stuck. Sorry :(

Comment: I mean that language authors won't do such thing because it is impossible to do in a sane way without losing flexibility, and end users of the language can't do that either because the language does not have necessary features (like implicits in Scala or metaclasses in Groovy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; you can't do that.

Default methods are not the same as extension methods; they can only be defined within the original interface.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate... I've been trying to figure out if this is possible for a while. I assume by your massive reputation that you are correct :). Any suggestions for making the streams api cleaner?

Comment: @Alden, unfortunately, Java does not have a solution for [expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), unlike Scala and other languages. So you have to create your own DSL-like wrappers (or just static functions, like in Guava) or use what is already exist.

Comment: Or you could always create a new collection object, use list as the backing type in the constructor and create all your functionality in the new collection object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a lightweight view to a `List` applying a `Function` and supporting chaining you can do it like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MappingList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
  // using this helper class we avoid carrying <S> with the public API
  static final class Source<E,S> {
      final List<S> list;
      final Function<? super S, ? extends E> mapper;
      Source(List<S> l, Function<? super S, ? extends E> m) {
          list=l;
          mapper=m;
      }
      E get(int index) { return mapper.apply(list.get(index)); }
      <T> Source map(Function<? super E, ? extends T> f) {
          Objects.requireNonNull(f);
          return new Source<>(list, mapper.andThen(f));
      }
      Stream<E> stream() { return list.stream().map(mapper); }
      Stream<E> parallelStream() { return list.parallelStream().map(mapper); }
    }
    final Source<E,?> source;

    private MappingList(Source<E,?> s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s);
        source=s;
    }
    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return source.get(index);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return source.list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return source.stream();
    }
    @Override
    public Stream<E> parallelStream() {
        return source.parallelStream();
    }
    public <T> MappingList<T> map(Function<? super E, ? extends T> f) {
        return new MappingList<>(source.map(f));
    }
    public static <S,T> MappingList<T> map(
      List<S> l, Function<? super S, ? extends T> f) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(l);
        if(l instanceof MappingList)
            return ((MappingList<S>)l).map(f);
        return new MappingList<>(new Source<>(l, f));
    }
}
```

It supports a GUAVA style creation of a mapped list while still allowing to use the `Stream` API with the mapped list evaluating all values lazily:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    List<String> strings=Arrays.asList("a", "simple", "list");
    List<Integer> ints=MappingList.map(strings, s->compute(s));
    List<Integer> results=MappingList.map(ints, i->compute(i));
    for(int result:results) {
        System.out.println("first result: "+result);
        System.out.println("Not computing any more values");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("  interacting with stream API:");
    System.out.println(results.stream().filter(i-> i>500).findFirst());
}
public static int compute(String s) {
    System.out.println("doing computation for "+s);
    return Integer.parseInt(s, 36);
}
public static int compute(int i) {
    System.out.println("doing computation for "+i);
    return i*i;
}
```

```
doing computation for a
doing computation for 10
first result: 100
Not computing any more values

  interacting with stream API:
doing computation for a
doing computation for 10
doing computation for simple
doing computation for 1724345618
Optional[410277188]
```

If you want to create a `List` with pre-calculated values out of it you can simply use `new ArrayList<>(mappedList)`.

Answer (score 1):

Eating my own dog's food and implementing what I suggested in a comment (UNTESTED, but it should work -- note that you should use `super` where appropriate, this is not my forte):

```
public final class ListTransformer<T>
{
    private final List<T> inputList;

    public static <X> ListTransformer<X> transform(final List<X> inputList)
    {
        return new ListTransformer<X>(inputList);
    }

    private ListTransformer(final List<T> inputList)
    {
        this.inputList = inputList;
    }

    public <U> List<U> using(final Function<T, U> f)
    {
        return inputList.stream().map(f).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import static wherever.is.ListTransformer.transform;

//
final List<String> names = transform(personList).using(x -> x.getName());
```

Comment: I'm sure you have meant `import static wherever.is.ListTransformer.transform` in your example :)

Comment: @Holger why not. But on the other hand, why not that? Some people prefer fluent interfaces...

Comment: @Holger and in my view it is _your_ solution which does not provide any benefit; ultimately this is a matter of tastes. The OP likes chaining, my solution provides chaining, your solution provides chaining, and that's about it

Answer (score 1):

C# extension methods are great and provide and easy mechanism to extend C# collections with own methods.

But now there are streams in java.
Based on [@fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) response I came with this snippet to write own extension methods on streams:

```
public final class StreamExtender<T>
{
    private final Stream<T> _inputStream;

    public static <T> StreamExtender<T> extend(final Stream<T> inputStream)
    {
        return new StreamExtender<>(inputStream);
    }

    private StreamExtender(final Stream<T> inputStream)
    {
        this._inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public <U> List<U> extensionMethod(final Function<T, U> f)
    {
        // your own code.
        return _inputStream.map(f).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And to see it in action:

```
Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3};
List<String> result = StreamExtender.extend(stream(array)).extensionMethod(Object::toString);
```